# Can I use a \caption in a tabu environment?

Tags: captions, tabu

Is it possible to use `\caption` between a `tabu` environment?

I have tried using these packages:

```
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tabu}
```

And when I write this in my code:

```
\begin{tabu} spread 2in{|X[2]|X[2]|X|X|X[2]|X[2]|}
%\caption{Marito}
\hline
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\
\hline
\end{tabu}
```

I get a lot of errors if I uncomment `\caption{Marito}`.

Note: The [Tabu documentation](http://mirrors.fe.up.pt/pub/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/tabu/tabu.pdf) doesn't say anything about it

Comment: No, it isn't, just like with `tabular`. The `\caption` doesn't belong in `tabu` or `tabular`.

Comment: If the table isn't breaking over the page surround the tabular (or tabu) with `\begin{table}..\end{table}` and put the caption in the `table` environment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per @egreg and @David Carlisle, `\caption` cannot be used in a `tabular` environment.  However, it is possible to used if wrapped around a `\begin{table}... \end{table}` environment as long as the table doesn't go in a pagebreak.

If so, `longtabu` can be used, and it has no problem with `\caption`.

Comment: For captions without floats use package `caption` or `capt-of` instead, but _outside_ of the `tabular` environment.

Answer (score 1):

tricky, though `tabu`, `longtabu` and `longtable` documentations definitely allow the `\caption`, but do not describe how to use them properly.

as mentioned by @cfr in [another thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/315336/caption-and-longtabu#comment769482_315336): put `\\` behind the `\caption[]{}` -- worked for me!

(to be more precise: no errors, but the caption is formatted completely differnt than all others in the document. Maybe the `caption` package will solve that)

Comment: Thats true it works fine.