# Caption and longtabu

Tags: captions, longtable, tabu

I am facing trouble including caption with a longtabu environment. The code is given below, which throws tons of errors.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tabu}

\begin{document}


\newpage 
\begin{longtabu} to 1\textwidth {l X[c] X[c] X[c] X[c] X[c] X[c] X[c]}
    \caption{Hello}
    \hline\hline
    $\Delta RealEstate_{region}$ = 1 &  0.004 & 0.003 & 0.010 & -0.003 &    0.010 \\
    $\Delta RealEstate_{region}$ = 2    &0.002& 0.003&  0.013&  -0.002& 0.008 \\
    $\Delta RealEstate_{region}$ = 3    &0.003& 0.003&  0.012&  -0.001& 0.009 \\
    $\Delta RealEstate_{region}$ = 4&   0.002&  0.003&  0.009&  -0.002& 0.007\\
    $\Delta RealEstate_{region}$ = 5&   0.005&  0.005&  0.011&  -0.002& 0.012\\
    $\Delta RealEstate_{region}$ = 6&   0.005&  0.005&  0.013&  -0.002& 0.012\\
    $\Delta RealEstate_{region}$ = 7&   0.004&  0.004&  0.008&  0.000&  0.009\\
    $\Delta RealEstate_{region}$ = 8&   0.003&  0.004&  0.011&  -0.001& 0.009\\
    $\Delta RealEstate_{region}$ = 9&   0.004&  0.003&  0.010&  -0.003& 0.011\\
    $\Delta RealEstate_{region}$ = 10&  0.002&  0.003&  0.006&  -0.001& 0.006\\
    $\Delta RealEstate_{region}$ = 11&  0.004&  0.004&  0.009&  0.000&  0.009\\
    $\Delta RealEstate_{region}$ = 12&  0.004&  0.004&  0.010&  -0.001& 0.009\\
    $\Delta RealEstate_{region}$ = 13&  0.003&  0.004&  0.013&  0.000&  0.007\\
    $\Delta RealEstate_{region}$ = 14&  0.004&  0.005&  0.011&  -0.002& 0.011\\
    $\Delta RealEstate_{region}$ = 15&  0.002&  0.002&  0.009&  -0.002& 0.007\\
    $\Delta RealEstate_{region}$ = 16&  0.004&  0.004&  0.010&  0.000&  0.010\\
    $\Delta RealEstate_{region}$ = 17&  0.002&  0.002&  0.010&  -0.002& 0.007\\
    $\Delta RealEstate_{region}$ = 18&  0.002&  0.003&  0.011&  0.000&  0.006\\
    $\Delta RealEstate_{region}$ = 19&  0.002&  0.003&  0.014&  -0.002& 0.008\\
    $\Delta RealEstate_{region}$ = 20&  0.004&  0.004&  0.012&  -0.002& 0.011\\
    $\Delta RealEstate_{region}$ = 21&  0.003&  0.006&  0.011&  -0.002& 0.010\\
    $\Delta RealEstate_{region}$ = 22&  0.003&  0.004&  0.009&  -0.002& 0.010\\
    $\Delta Prof$&  0.000&  0.001&  0.020&  -0.006& 0.008\\
    RETURN& 0.020&  0.022&  0.071&  -0.019& 0.065\\
    GDP&    0.024&  0.025&  0.032&  0.013&  0.042\\
    TBILL&  0.057&  0.056&  0.036&  0.033&  0.079\\
    INFLATION&  0.043&  0.035&  0.035&  0.024&  0.057\\
    CORP&   0.101&  0.067&  0.243&  -0.068& 0.222\\
    TERM&   -0.012& -0.013& 0.012&  -0.020& -0.003\\
    $\Delta Prof_{region}$ =1&  0.002&  0.003&  0.028&  -0.008& 0.014\\
    $\Delta Prof_{region}$ =2&  -0.001& 0.000&  0.030&  -0.013& 0.014\\
    $\Delta Prof_{region}$ =3&  0.001&  0.002&  0.042&  -0.009& 0.014\\
    $\Delta Prof_{region}$ =4&  0.000&  0.001&  0.021&  -0.008& 0.011\\
    $\Delta Prof_{region}$ =5&  0.011&  0.007&  0.066&  -0.014& 0.043\\
    $\Delta Prof_{region}$ =6&  0.009&  0.006&  0.035&  -0.009& 0.027\\
    $\Delta Prof_{region}$ =7&  -0.001& 0.001&  0.066&  -0.028& 0.026\\
    $\Delta Prof_{region}$ =8&  0.002&  0.000&  0.027&  -0.008& 0.007\\
    $\Delta Prof_{region}$ =9&  -0.001& 0.001&  0.035&  -0.011& 0.013\\
    $\Delta Prof_{region}$ =10& -0.002& 0.000&  0.043&  -0.010& 0.015\\
    $\Delta Prof_{region}$ =11& -0.002& 0.000&  0.030&  -0.017& 0.015\\
    $\Delta Prof_{region}$ =12& 0.006&  0.007&  0.052&  -0.022& 0.029\\
    $\Delta Prof_{region}$ =13& 0.004&  0.000&  0.291&  -0.020& 0.020\\
    $\Delta Prof_{region}$ =14& 0.002&  0.004&  0.021&  -0.010& 0.015\\
    $\Delta Prof_{region}$ =15& -0.003& 0.001&  0.039&  -0.014& 0.012\\
    $\Delta Prof_{region}$ =16& 0.000&  0.000&  0.026&  -0.013& 0.016\\
    $\Delta Prof_{region}$ =17& -0.003& 0.001&  0.040&  -0.008& 0.012\\
    $\Delta Prof_{region}$ =18& -0.007& -0.002& 0.046&  -0.010& 0.006\\
    $\Delta Prof_{region}$ =19& 0.010&  0.008&  0.083&  -0.015& 0.028\\
    $\Delta Prof_{region}$ =20& 0.000&  0.002&  0.029&  -0.009& 0.012\\
    $\Delta Prof_{region}$ =21& 0.002&  0.003&  0.028&  -0.008& 0.014\\
    $\Delta Prof_{region}$ =22& 0.002&  0.003&  0.021&  -0.007& 0.011
\end{longtabu}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Try `\\ ` after `\caption{}`. Just a guess. I wouldn't touch `tabu` with a barge pole, personally.

Comment: @cfr why would you not touch tabu? Is tabularx a better environment compared to tabu? Why?

Comment: Because the author has promised an update which will break existing documents and, in the meantime, doesn't think it worth fixing bugs. At least, so it has been reported here. There was discussion around of it, but I don't know if it was in comments or regular posts, so it might have been deleted or difficult to find.

Comment: See the discussion [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/106511/how-to-create-a-dashed-line-in-tabularx-environment/106522#106522) and considerably more critical [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/121841/is-the-tabu-package-obsolete/121847#121847).

Comment: Definitely [read this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/comp.text.tex/xRGJTC74uCI/bDD-jypImbQJ).

Comment: Eye-opening, isn't it? I thought people were exaggerating until I read the original thread.

Comment: @cfr It is for sure.

Comment: Use `multicolumn` text as the first table row. See this [https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/329926/longtabu-table-with-captionsetuplabelsep-newline-problem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/329926/longtabu-table-with-captionsetuplabelsep-newline-problem)

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to use `\caption{}` within `tabu`, simply add `\\` at the end of the line, e.g.:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tabu}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtabu}{l}
    \caption{This is a caption} \\
    This is some table data \\
\end{longtabu}

\end{document}
```

Any credits go to @cfr who already explained the solution within the [comment section](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/315336/caption-and-longtabu#comment769482_315336), but unfortunately did not provide an answer (according to the SE question-answer paradigm) and hence, lazy people (like me) might miss the solution.