# longtabu table with captionsetup{labelsep=newline} problem

Tags: tables, captions, longtabu

I would like to create the table below with the "labelsep=newline"option in \captionsetup{}. However, I get an error message. Without the "labelsep=newline" parameter the code is running fine (see example). 
Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

```
\documentclass[float=false, crop=false]{standalone}
\usepackage{collcell}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{longtable,tabu}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper, top=25mm, left=40mm, right=25mm, bottom=30mm,
    headsep=10mm, footskip=12mm}
\captionsetup[table]{justification=centering,labelsep=newline}
%\captionsetup[table]{justification=centering}
\begin{document}
{\footnotesize
\begin{longtabu} to \textwidth {
    X[15,l]
    X[4,l]
    X[6,l]
    X[8,l]
    }
    \caption{Caption 1}\\
    \caption*{Caption 2}\\
    \label{tab:table genral information es50} \\
    \hline \hline \hline \hline
    \textbf{Column 1} & 
    \textbf{Column 2} &
    \textbf{Column 3} &
    \textbf{Column 4} 

    \\  \hline \hline \hline \hline   
                            &        &         &  \\
     entry& entry     & entry & entry\\
     entry & entry           & entry & entry\\
     entry & entry                          & entry & entry\\
\end{longtabu}
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: in `longtable`, the caption is faked by having it imitade a `multicolumn` for the whole span of that row.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, Runar Trollet. However, I do not fully understand how it helps me to achieve the result I desire. Or do you think it is not possible to have the caption appear in the same style as it would by \captionsetup{justification=centering,labelsep=newline} in a regular table environment?

Comment: See my answer for info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### `longtable` and captions

The reason for this is that for `longtable` to be able to split a table into pages, it cannot be in a floating environment. This is problematic for the `\caption`-macro, which need to be in a floating environment, like `table` or `figure`. To get around this, `longtable` redefines the `\caption`-macro, essentially making it only some text in a `multicolumn`

This is described in the documentation for `longtable` Note that you can always locate the documentation using the command-line/terminal by writing `texdoc longtable`, and that works for any package. The documentation is also available at http://ctan.org/pkg/longtable

### Why is this probematic for us?

when you specify that the seperator for labels should be a newline, that means that a `\\` will be inserted after *Table #*, but in tables, `\\`, means something more than just to insert a newline, as you already know, it will create a new row, which gives us an error since we are effectively inside a `multicolumn` now, because of the redefenition of `\caption`, as mentioned above.

### Solution

Add a new label seperator, with the command

```
\DeclareCaptionLabelSeparator{tableNewline}{\par}
```

which we will use only in `longtables`. This will give us the intended result. The downside is that we have need to keep track of two different formats.

#### Output

[image]

#### Code

```
\documentclass[float=false, crop=false]{standalone}
\usepackage{collcell}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}% some new rules for tables
\DeclareCaptionLabelSeparator{tableNewline}{\par}
\geometry{a4paper, top=25mm, left=40mm, right=25mm, bottom=30mm,
    headsep=10mm, footskip=12mm}
\captionsetup{
  justification=centering,
  labelsep=newline,
  }
\captionsetup[longtable]{
  justification=centering,
  labelsep=tableNewline,
  }
\begin{document}

\begin{table}

  \caption{Some test caption for a regular table}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{ll}
    \toprule
    Foo & Baz \\
    \midrule
    baz & foobaz \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
{\footnotesize

\begin{longtabu} to \textwidth {
    X[15,l]
    X[4,l]
    X[6,l]
    X[8,l]
    }
    \caption{Caption 1}
    \label{tab:table genral information es50} \\
    \toprule
    \textbf{Column 1} &
    \textbf{Column 2} &
    \textbf{Column 3} &
    \textbf{Column 4}
    \\
    \midrule
                            &        &         &  \\
     entry& entry     & entry & entry\\
     entry & entry           & entry & entry\\
     entry & entry                          & entry & entry\\
     \bottomrule
\end{longtabu}
}
\end{document}
```

[image: Fixed longtable caption with newline]